# ImageDataGenerator performs worse

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I build a neural network with and without ImageDataGenerator. When I use it without than it works fine. When I use it with IDG than both accuracy and valid_accuracy-scores are really bad. So I think I am doing something wrong.

I wanted to use the IDG to see what augmentation could do for my neural network. But even when I get rid of all the augmentation it still performs bad.

Here is my code for the IDG:

```
image_size=224

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split = 0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('images',
target_size = (image_size, image_size),
batch_size = 10
class_mode = 'categorical'
subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('images',
target_size = (image_size, image_size),
batch_size = 10
class_mode = 'categorical'
subset='training')
```

When I fit it I use this code:

```
    chat = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // 10,
validation_data = validation_generator,
validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 10,
epochs = 10)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Does the IDG perform an operation on the images that I don't see but changes something that influences the images in some way?

When I plot my images, I don't see anything strange.

Hope someone can give me some tips!

Comment: Could it have something to do with the steps_per_epoch or validation_steps?

Comment: What steps could I take to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: ```steps_per_epoch``` is the number of batches the training generator should yield before considering an epoch finished. If you have 600 training images with batch size 20, this would be 30 steps per epoch. ```validation_steps``` applies the same logic to the validation data generator, be it at the end of each epoch.

Comment: Did you used any transfer learning for your network ? It could be that your transfer learning weights are not compatible with your image dimension.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that the performance is worse with data augmentation, are you comparing both on the same dataset?

Generally there is a chance of mistake of comparing the accuracy of model trained with data augmentation on the augmented dataset with the model trained without data augmentation on the regular dataset.

It is important to keep in mind that augmented datasets can be harder to deal with for the model. Therefore, even if the accuracy isn't as high as before, it might be actually higher when evaluated on the regular dataset.